# Как сделать подгрузку файлов игры с сервера при запуске на андроид?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка, unity3d-faq

Дайте пожалуйста направление как загружать файлы с сервера при запуске игры, чтобы в будущем можно было добавлять/менять фон, музыку и т.д.

Comment: Добавил в FAQ потому что очень полезная штука при мобильной разработке. Маст-хэв во множестве проектов.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Основная часть ассетов входит в сам проект еще на стадии компиляции, а это значит то, что просто загрузить файл и им пользоваться не выйдет. Все файлы буквально встраиваются в сам проект на стадии компиляции.

Но иногда нужно доступ к файлам через pathname. Например: проигрывание видео на iOS осуществимо только по path. Или, скажем, подкачка новых ресурсов из интернета и подгрузка их в рантайме. Это возможно при помощи [Streaming Assets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).

Как пользоватся этим -- в мануале по линке. Копай в эту сторону.

Если грубо и коротко:

1. Создаешь папку в проекте StreamingAssets
2. Учишься обращаться к файлам которые лежат в этой папке (обращение осуществляется по конкретному пути, а не так как обычно в unity)
3. При помощи http запроса сохраняешь файл туда, например, zip папку с нужными ресурсами в правильной структуре, разархивируешь в эту же папку и обращаешься к ресурсам в рантайме.

Так же нужно иметь ввиду, что стандартные ресурсы конвертируются в "стандартные форматы" для юнити и оптимизируются. Так же нужно иметь ввиду что если не подготовить ресурс, он будет медленнее работать т.к. юнити будет конвертировать ресурсы "на лету". Например сжимать текстуры.

## Так же, пожалуста, заплюсуйте ответ KingPeas.

Он дополнил ответ очень хорошим путем -- [Asset Bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html). Думаю, даже лучшим чем сначала вспомнил я :)

Они созданы именно для того, что бы подготовить и упростить загрузку (т.к. все ресурсы нужные можно в 1 файл закинуть и, например, текстуры сразу пережимаются юнити, а не на лету это делается, как в случае со Streaming Assets.)

Answer (score 14):

Посмотрите в сторону [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) - это встроенный механизм от Unity для закачки контента отдельными пакетами. Это позволит добавлять контент порционно) Например подгружать контент от моделей до новых сцен.