# Как создать папку для видео и привязать ее к приложению android unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Я хочу чтобы мое приложение брало из определенной папки видео. По умолчанию у меня есть папка resources, но как я понимаю она вшивается в apk, и поэтому к ней доступа нет. То есть мне просто нужно сделать папку для перемещения в нее видео. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Хотя на первый взгляд эти 2 вопроса между собой не связаны, на практике они являются одним целым.: [Как сделать подгрузку файлов игры с сервера при запуске на андроид?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919350/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Comment: @Andrew тут суть в другом. Мне нужно открывать видео. Видео у меня хранятся не на облаке, а на устройстве. И мне сойдет способ просто через приложение создать папку для видео, чтобы для юзера нужно было просто переместить. Как указать например путь для этой папки? storage/folder так что-ли?

Comment: Вопрос в другом, а решение одно и то же. Твой путь - StreamingAssets. Закинешь видео туда - выйдет его открывать по пути в папке. А иначе - прийдется делать платформо-зависимый код.

Comment: Окроме того вопрос в принципе расплывчастый. Нужно что бы открывался внешний файл внешним видеоплеером? Тогда через OpenUrl достаточно его открыть указав абсолютный путь к файлу.

Comment: @Andrew так да, я так и хочу сделать.