# Большой вес проекта юнити 2д

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Я пишу игру на юнити 2д. Визуальную новеллу, если точнее. При компиляции я получаю неприлично-большой размер файла(пишу под андроид). Есть какие-то способы облегчить мой апк? Я пытался нахимичить в buid settings, но это не дало значительного результата. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. По началу следует понять "а что собственно весит то?" Обычно слишком много весит графика (я не думаю что в проекте много кода. Графику можно попробовать пожать отдельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вводим в гугл "как уменьшить размер apk unity" и заходим на любую попавшийся статью. Например у меня показывает при беглом взгляде вполне подходящую статью: https://habr.com/ru/post/250873/ . В общем по данному запросу можно найти много информации, уверяю, этим вопросом задавались многие.

   Еще будет полезной Player settings > other settings > Optimization
2. Размер изображений. Пережать их всех максимальным способом. Это сбережёт ну ооооочень много места.
3. Музыка и звуки. Здесь твоя задача как и из изображениями просто ужать звуки по-максимуму. Например, стерео в даном жанре игры для телефонов вообще бесполезно и все звуки ужимаются сходу в 2 раза какой бы формат ни был использован. А там уже поиграйся с настройками компрессии, желательно, в OGG.

Бонус:

Как один из вариантов решения проблемы большого дистрибутива -- можно докачивать ресурсы из интернета.

Например, при первом запуске игры смотреть какое разрешение экрана у данного девайса и под него докачивать уже нужный блок ресурсов заточенных под непосредственно именно это разрешение.

Вот здесь вопрос касается того как это делать: [Как сделать подгрузку файлов игры с сервера при запуске на андроид?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919350/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4/919353#919353)

---

И, все же, я настоятельно рекомендую сменить движок с Юнити на любой, который заточен под визуальные новеллы. Не потому, что игра "много занимает", а потому что грузить полноценное 3д двигало что бы отображать пару картинок на экране и блок текста - это по меньшей мере неуважение к конечному пользователю. Ты будешь жрать ресурсы телефона в 20 раз больше чем того требует задача. А использование лишних ресурсов телефона = использование батареи.

Comment: спасибо, вы помогли. Ответ хоть и общий, но некоторые тонкости я из него вынес