# Как уменьшить размер билда в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Делаю небольшую игру викторину с большим количеством текстур высокого разрешения. Проблема в том что после билда приложение весит слишком много. Хотелось бы узнать, если какой-нибудь способ уменьшить размер приложения не жертвуя при этом качеством текстур. Можно ли текстуры сохранить в каком-нибудь облаке/сервере и загружать их оттуда в игру во время ее запуска?

Comment: Можете попробовать ассет бандлы и что-то типа такого https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle.html. Либо вручную загружать как файлы. С ними же можно играться со сжатием, юнити его предоставляет из коробки и оно весьма настраиваемое.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Большой вес проекта юнити 2д](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137089/%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8-2%d0%b4)